# Add user meta after a user has registered and logged In

Tags: plugins, wp-query, theme-development, user-meta, profiles

I have a very simple question . I am building a wordpress site where a after a user is created and  logged in , there will be a link where he can click and add more information about him / her (let's say add Business info ) .

I don't want to spend time in doing this as i believe there are enough plugins that can achieve this . i tried [wordpress user-meta](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-meta/) , but unfortunately it only supports adding user meta during registration .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add user meta after login by using the `wp_login` hook. Make sure to set a higher priority (99 - the default is 10) to make sure to get the data after everything has processed in the core `wp_signon()` function.

From the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login) ...

```
function add_my_user_meta_after_login( $user_login, $user ) {
 //Add my user meta code
}
add_action('wp_login', 'add_my_user_meta_after_login', 99, 2);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your support , i am sure i can accomplish that with your code . But the issue is i have a deadline and don't wanna spend a lot of time creating a functionality for this as i have a lot of fields to integrate . Is there a plugin out there that does the exact thing that your aware of ?Thanks again for helping.

Comment: This process may help you. 

a) Create a redirect callback 


`my_registration_redirect() {
    return home_url( '/my-page' );
}

add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'my_registration_redirect' );`



b) You can then use any form builder plugin to create your form (I'd recommend Ninja Form [link](https://ninjaforms.com/)). After that use a shortcode generated by the form buider and place it on a page with the same slug as 'my-page' in the above redirect.